# ClosedXML does not open Excel workbooks with pivot table

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop, closedxml

I am kind of new to the ClosedXMLimplementation so please forgive if this is a dumb question. I would like to consolidate data from multiple spreadsheets using ClosedXML. I was able to pull data from different workbooks until I tried to pull from a workbook that contains a pivot table on one of the sheets. 
It throws an "Exception Unhandled" error with the following description

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

---

Here is the code - though I do not think there is an issue with the code

```
            using (var fromWorkbook = new XLWorkbook(xlFile))
            using (var toWorkbook = new XLWorkbook(Constants.excelPath2))
            {
                var ws1 = fromWorkbook.Worksheet(1);
                var initialRow1 = ws1.FirstRowUsed().RowUsed();
                var firstPossibleAddress = ws1.Row(initialRow1.RowNumber()).FirstCellUsed().Address;
                var lastPossibleAddress = ws1.LastCellUsed().Address;
                ws1Range = ws1.Range(firstPossibleAddress, lastPossibleAddress);

                foreach (IXLWorksheet ws2 in toWorkbook.Worksheets)
                {
                    if (ws2.Name.Contains(fNameTrimmed(xlFile)))
                    {
                        var initialRow2 = ws2.FirstRow();
                        initialRow2.Cell(1).Value = ws1Range;
                    }
                }
                toWorkbook.Save();
            }
```

I have tried to re-run the script with the same file after deleting the pivot table and it went through with no issues. Does anyone know a workaround for this problem and can point me to the right direction please?

Thanks

Comment: Pivot tables are still work in progress. Please log an issue on the Github page, post your code and attach the problematic Excel file. (PS: I'm a developer on ClosedXML)